# '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'- how to convert to execute and operation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, statsmodels

I want to perform the following operation:

```
df_final[quarter_dates]=df_final[quarter_dates].multiply(daily_cost_df, axis=0)
```

quarter dates was generated as follows:

```
quarter_dates = pd.date_range("2020-1-01", freq="Q", periods = 32).date
```

the error that I am receiving while attempting to run the first operation is as follows:

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'str'
```

quarter dates and daily cost dataframe are both 129,32 in shape.

Comment: Please provide a small set of sample data as text that we can copy and paste. Include the corresponding desired result. Check out the guide on [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3620003).

Comment: There is no comparison in your question. The error may come from some other line of your code.